# How to get max Value Unit from field Value Unit based on first value before comma separated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I work on SQL server 2012 I face issue :i can't get first max value from value Unit based on First value before comma .

as example This value Unit below :

```
1.89, 2.625, 3.465
```

I will get first value before comma separated as 1.89 then if this number is max value return full number
exist on Value Unit

```
create table #finaltable
(
partid  int,
ValueUnit nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #finaltable(partid,ValueUnit)
values
(2532,'1.71, 2.375, 3.135'),
(2532,'1.89, 2.625, 3.465')
select * from #finaltable
```

How to get first max value from field ValueUnit based on first value before comma separated ?

Expected Result returned :

```
1.89, 2.625, 3.465
```

because 1.89 is maximum number from 1.71 then I returned full number

Comment: Stop storing delimited data, and you won't have such a hard time. Especially with data like that, if you have a value like `N'10.12, 12.756, 15.423'` then `N'10.12'` could be the **lowest** of the first strings, not the highest.

Comment: Agree with the above; you should seriously fix your data model and move away from storing CSV in your tables.  If you _must_ store CSV, then let it just be static data; don't try to do math on it as you are attempting above.

Comment: can you add another answer again I notice it is deleted so please can you re back added it –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments, your design is bad. For more on that, you should also read ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

But well, you can use `patindex()` to get the position of the comma and then extract the first number representation with `left()`. `convert()` it to some `decimal`, order by it and take the `TOP 1` row.

```
SELECT TOP 1
       *
       FROM #finaltable
       ORDER BY convert(decimal(4, 3), left(valueunit, patindex('%,%', valueunit) - 1)) DESC;
```

You may need to tweak the conversion to a `decimal`. I don't know what maximum length and precision you may need.

Comment: can you add another answer again I notice it is deleted so please can you re back added it

Comment: @ahmedbarbary: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I didn't delete this answer. Clearly, as otherwise you wouldn't be able to comment it...